How to close parent popup when closing child popup?
I'm working on a web application in Angular where I need to handle nested popups. Specifically, I have a situation where I open a popup (Popup 1) and from within that popup, I open another popup (Popup 2) when clicking on delete. What I want to achieve is that when I click "Yes" on Popup 2, both Popup 1 and Popup 2 should be closed.
Here is a full demo of my code:
Demo@StackBlitz

Thanks for the stackblitz. We have a method called closeAll, we can use this to close both popups.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { CofirmDialogComponent } from '../cofirm-dialog/cofirm-dialog.component';
import { filter } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DialogService {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}
  public deleteTaskDialog(id: number) {
    this.dialog
      .open(CofirmDialogComponent, {})
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(filter((id) => id))
      .subscribe((confirm) => {
        this.dialog.closeAll(); // <- changed here!
      });
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
